# Как переместить теги на страницу постов

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

**Django 2.1.4**
Есть блог - нужно переместить все теги из blog/tags на основную страницу (blog/) :
[image: изображение1]
Теги:
[image: изображение2]
*urls.py:*

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url'),
    path('tags/', tags_list, name='tags_list_url'),
]
```

views.py:

```
def tags_list(request):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/tags_list.html', context={'tags': tags})
```

main/tags_list.html

```
{% extends 'main/base_main.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Tag - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="mb-5">All tags:</h1>

    {% for tag in tags %}
        <h2><a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></h2>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

base_main.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block admin-panel %}

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Create
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'post_create_url' %}">Post</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'tag_create_url' %}">Tag</a>
  </div>
</div>

    <a href="{{ admin_object.get_update_url }}" class="btn btn-light edit" style="{% if detail %}display:block;{% endif %}">Edit</a>
    <a href="{{ admin_object.get_delete_url }}" class="btn btn-danger delete" style="{% if detail %}display:block;{% endif %}">Delete</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: И в чём вопрос? Нужно - перемещайте.

Comment: Я новичок в Django, и не могу понять как это реализовать.

Comment: [Руководство Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/) прочитали полностью?

Comment: Дааа, от установки до расширения админки.